# Using String to Select From

Tags: google-bigquery

So I've got a tables being imported daily from firebase and I'm exporting them from google cloud to power bi. The naming schema stays roughly the same, the only thing that changes daily is the date at the end of the table name. Been trying to create a query that makes the process fully automated, but I've been stuck. The concat is correct, but the string doesn't work to call from. Help is appreciated.

```
DECLARE Query STRING(100);
SET Query = CONCAT("report-viewer.analytics_278375497.events_", FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()));

SELECT  
    //Various stuff

FROM Query LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) in this scenario

Using your particular simplified example  - it could look like below

```
DECLARE table_reference STRING(100);

SET table_reference = 'report-viewer.analytics_278375497.events_' || FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE());

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
'''SELECT  //Various stuff
FROM `''' || table_reference || '''` LIMIT 1000
''');
```

Comment: Can you show how it'd be meant to be used? Rather at a loss here as to its implementation for this scenario.

Comment: sure. added example to my answer

Comment: so I'm trying to use this, but it seems its erroring out on other declared parameters in the SQL. is there other formatting needed when using other declares in the WHERE clause?